# How to find the coordinates of my touch event?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, dumpsys

I am testing a third party game on physical device after connecting with `adb` on Windows. I am capturing logs using:

```
adb -d logcat > logcat.txt
```

During testing I tap on the game screen for a few times.
How to find the coordinates of my touch event?

Comment: do you have access to the source code?

Comment: no, i dont. Suppose i am testing any internal package like com.android.browser and i tap on browser screen, will my touch event recorded somewhere in logcat?

Comment: as far as i know nope, touch events are not logged automatically on logcat, you need to add code in order to print touches on logcat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38692705/1778421

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is an old question, but still hope that i could help someone:

Please, take a look on https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys

Accessing shell directly and running dumpsys with input option returns what you're seeking.

```
adb shell dumpsys input
```

Answer (score 0):

The touch events do not get logged to the `logcat` by default. 
You need to use `adb shell getevent` or `adb shell dumpsys input` instead.

Comment: `adb shell getevent -l`, (-l: label event types and names in plain text). so you can easily figure out which is `ABS_MT_POSITION_X` / `ABS_MT_POSITION_Y`.