# Log the Key Event when using Adb input

Tags: android, logging, adb

I use the command `adb shell su -- getevent -lt /dev/input/event5 > Test.txt` to log the touch event. It works when I touch the screen, i.e, it writes all actions (key down, key move and key up with the coordinates).

But, when I use the command `adb shell input tap x y` to simulate the touch, even if the device get the event (for example, the app is opened) but in the log file, there is no log lines about this tap.

How can I log the simulate the key event touch with `adb`?

Comment: How were you able to get the `adb shell su -- getevent -lt /dev/input/event5 > Test.txt` command to work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680235/how-can-i-redirect-androids-getevent-output-to-a-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for you not being to see your `input tap` events in the `getevent` output is that `sendevent` and `getevent` work with Linux kernel input events and `input` command injects the events directly into the Android input event queue.

[This (old but still useful) article](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/internal-input-event-handling-in-the-linux-kernel-and-the-android-userspace.html) has some nice diagrams illustrating the input event propagation in Android.

Unfortunately there is no easy (ready to use) way to do what you asked for. The closest thing I could think of is using `dumpsys input` command - it shows last 10 input events (including ones injected by the `input` command) in the *RecentQueue:* section.

Comment: Ah thank you for your answer. I tried `adb shell dumpsys input` and it works. It gets the log as I want.